# TaskCanceledException when not awaiting

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I seem to be getting a `TaskCanceledException` whenever I return another Task synchronously instead of awaiting it, following the guidelines in [When at last you await](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229662.aspx).

### TaskCanceledException code

```
public static class Download
{
    public static Task<byte[]> FromYouTubeAsync(string videoUri)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            return FromYouTubeAsync(
                () => client
                .GetStringAsync(videoUri),
                uri => client
                .GetByteArrayAsync(uri));
        }
    }

    public async static Task<byte[]> FromYouTubeAsync(
        Func<Task<string>> sourceFactory, Func<string, Task<byte[]>> downloadFactory)
    {
        string source = await // TaskCanceledException here
            sourceFactory()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        // find links

        return await
            downloadFactory(links.First())
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

### Exception-free code

Here, the first overload of the method's signature is changed to async, and it awaits the second overload. For some reason, this prevents the `TaskCanceledException`.

```
public static class Download
{
    public async static Task<byte[]> FromYouTubeAsync(string videoUri)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            return await FromYouTubeAsync(
                () => client
                .GetStringAsync(videoUri),
                uri => client
                .GetByteArrayAsync(uri));
        }
    }

    public async static Task<byte[]> FromYouTubeAsync(
        Func<Task<string>> sourceFactory, Func<string, Task<byte[]>> downloadFactory)
    {
        string source = await // No exception!
            sourceFactory()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        // find links

        return await
            downloadFactory(links.First())
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Why does this happen and what can I do to fix it (**besides** awaiting the method, which wastes resources as described in the link above)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, the [link you posted](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229662.aspx) is about *applying an optimization* which is *only applicable if the method does nothing after its `await`*. To quote the post:

> In this case, however, we’re being handed a task to represent the last statement in the method, and thus it’s in effect already a representation of the entire method’s processing...

In your example, the task does *not* represent the last statement in the method. Look again:

```
public async static Task<byte[]> FromYouTubeAsync(string videoUri)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    return await FromYouTubeAsync(...);
  }
}
```

There's something happening *after* the `await`: specifically, the disposing of `client`. So the optimization mentioned in that blog post *does not apply here*.

This is why you're seeing an exception if you try to return the task directly:

```
public static Task<byte[]> FromYouTubeAsync(string videoUri)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    return FromYouTubeAsync(...);
  }
}
```

This code is starting the download, *then disposing the `HttpClient`*, and then returning the task. `HttpClient` will cancel any outstanding operations when it is disposed.

The code using `await` will (asynchronously) wait for the HTTP operation to complete before it disposes the `HttpClient`. That is the behavior you need, and `await` is the cleanest way to express it. In this case, it's not a "waste of resources" at all, because you *have* to defer disposing until after the download completes.

Comment: Great explanation. I wonder if the `HttpClient` should throw an `ObjectDisposedException` instead, because the vague error messages were just confusing. Thank you for your help!